# Running a js file with node is giving me an "HTMLDivElement" is not defined. Do i need to import it, or is that specific to browsers outside of Node?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I was trying to run some tests, but needed test data, so i created a generation file which created dummy html.  When I attempt to run it though, it gives me a *Reference Error: HTMLDivElement is not defined.*

Is there something I need to import such that Node knows what HTMLDivElement is?  I am not rendering anything, but just want correct data to pipe into follow on code.

I run my file through TSC, and then run it through node.

Sample Code:

```
const main = () => {
    let root = new HTMLDivElement();
}
main();
```

Edit:

I was trying to just bypass it with: `let root = document.createElement("div");` but node does not understand what document is, so I cant seem to get that running either as a fallback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, Node.js doesn't come with a DOM implementation.  If you want to run tests that use the DOM, you'll need to either load a Node.js-compatible DOM implementation such as [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom), or if that doesn't meet your requirements, switch to a browser-based testing environment such as [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: You are correct.  I ended up leveraging JSDOM through The MockBrowser utilities.  Then I created an implementation of `import {mocks} from 'mock-browser'; var MockBrowser = mocks.MockBrowser;
var mock = new MockBrowser();
var document = mock.getDocument()`
Something that also needs to be noted, is that JSDOM doesnt have all utilities that the browsers do.  So instead of me saying:  `document.all` i will say `document.querySelectorAll("*")`